# ¿Cómo puedo validar que al ingresar una cadena el dato se vuelva 0?

Tags: vue.js

Me encuentro haciendo una práctica donde estoy recibiendo datos en 4 inputs. Hay una función que hace una operación de suma y una función reset; ahora lo que quiero hacer es que si alguien ingresa una letra el valor se haga 0 porque las sumas ya no cuadran, por ejemplo:

suma uno:e
suma dos:4
suma cinco:4
suma diez: 4
resultado: e444

Con puros enteros la suma se hace correctamente.

Lo que quiero es que cuando haya una letra se haga 0 el campo para que haga una suma bien.

```
<template>
 <v-container>
   <!--  -->
  <v-form
   ref="form"
  @submit.prevent="submit"
  >
    <v-layout row>
      <v-flex xs12 md12 sm12 class="">
        <v-text-field
          class="mt-3"
          label=" $1"
          v-model="uno"
        ></v-text-field>
        <v-text-field
          class="mx-1"
          label=" $2"
          v-model="dos"
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-flex>

      <v-flex xs12 md12 sm12 >
        <v-text-field
          class="mt-3 mx-1"
          label=" $5"
          v-model="cinco"
        ></v-text-field>
        <v-text-field
          class=""
          label="$10"
          v-model="diez"
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-flex>

      <v-flex xs12  sm12 md12>
        <v-btn type="submit" @click="sumaMonedas" value="Enviar">Calcular</v-btn>
      </v-flex>
      <!-- Dialog -->
    </v-layout>
  </v-form>
  <v-dialog
        class="mt-n-10"
        v-model="dialog"
        max-width="500px"
      >
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
         {{ resultado }}
          </v-card-title>
          <v-card-text>
          </v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-btn
              color="primary"
              text
              @click="dialog= false"
            >
              Close
            </v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
 </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Form-main',
    data: () => ({ 
      uno: '',
      dos: '',
      cinco: '',
      diez: '',
      resultado: '',
      dialog: '',
    }),

    methods:  {
      submit() {
        this.sumaMonedas()
        this.reset()
      },

      validaInput() {
        
      },

      sumaMonedas() {
        this.resultado = parseInt(this.uno) + parseInt(this.dos) + parseInt(this.cinco)
        + parseInt(this.diez)
        this.dialog = true
      },

      reset() {
        this.uno= null
        this.dos= null
        this.cinco=null
        this.diez= null
      }
    },
  }
</script>
 
<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede utilizar una expresión regular y en caso que no sea un número reasignarle a la variable el valor de 0, algo similar a esto:

```
submit() {
  // Expresión regular para comprobar si el valor es un número
  const numberRegex = /^\d+$/;

  // Valores de los campos de texto
  let uno = this.uno;
  let dos = this.dos;
  let cinco = this.cinco;
  let diez = this.diez;

  // Si alguno de los valores no es un número, se asigna el valor 0 al campo de texto
  if (!numberRegex.test(uno)) uno = 0;
  if (!numberRegex.test(dos)) dos = 0;
  if (!numberRegex.test(cinco)) cinco = 0;
  if (!numberRegex.test(diez)) diez = 0;

  // Realizar la suma y asignar el resultado a la variable "resultado"
  let resultado = Number(uno) + Number(dos) + Number(cinco) + Number(diez);

  // Mostrar el resultado en la consola
  console.log(resultado);
}
```